# How do you check coverage of a single file with Istanbul?

Tags: javascript, node.js, istanbul, karma-coverage

I'm running test coverage with karma/jasmine on my Angular project and output the coverage to a file `./coverage/coverage.json`.

I can then run a command like:

```
./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js check-coverage --lines 90 
Output: ERROR: Coverage for lines (89.1%) does not meet global threshold (90%)
```

This gets me global test coverage.

But what I want to do is check the coverage of just one file. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be built into istanbul, but what I can do is create a summary JSON and read that with node after running it in terminal.

First, the Karma config needs to generate a JSON summary with files as keys:

```
coverageReporter: {
    reporters: [
        {type: 'json-summary', subdir: './', file: 'coverage.json'}
    ]
}
```

Then you can run a terminal task to get all the staged files in git.

```
(gulp karma)

ROOT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
STAGED_FILES=($(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep ".js$"))

for file in ${STAGED_FILES}; do
  echo "gulp coverage -f $ROOT_DIR/$file"
  git show :$file | gulp coverage -f "$ROOT_DIR/$file"
done;
```

And the gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('coverage', function () {
    var threshold = 90;
    var coverageJSON = require('./coverage/coverage.json');

    var metrics = [ 'lines', 'statements', 'functions', 'branches' ];
    for (var i in metrics) {
        if (coverageJSON[ argv.f ][ metrics[ i ] ].pct < threshold) {
            console.log('ERROR:', argv.f, 'does not meet', threshold, 'percent coverage of', metrics[ i ]);
            process.exit(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Technically, the terminal part can be done using `exec` in node but I wanted a shell command so I can do pre-commit execution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this with config file.

```
instrumentation:
   excludes: [ '!yourfile.js' ]
```

does the trick.